# A standard name for a function satisfying the intermediate value theorem?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, terminology

Do you know any (standard) name for a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ having the following weak intermediate value property:

> $(*)$ for any connected subset $C\subset \mathbb R$ and points $a,b\in C$ with $f(a)< f(b)$ there exists a point  $x\in C\setminus\{a,b\}$ such that $f(a)\le f(x)\le f(b)$.

---

**Remark 1.** Functions with a bit stronger property:

> $(S)$ for any connected subset $C\subset \mathbb R$ and points $a,b\in C$ with $f(a)<f(b)$ there exists a continuity point $x\in C$ of $f$ such that $f(a)<f(x)<f(b)$

are called *Świątkowski* functions.

**Remark 2.** Another stronger property

> $(D)$ for any connected subset $C\subset \mathbb R$ the image $f(C)$ is connected

is called the *[Darboux property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_function)*.

So, functions with (*) can be called either *weak Świątkowski* function or *weak Darboux* functions. Are there any other names or ideas?

---

**Motivation:** I need to call somehow this property $(*)$ since I can prove a nice

> **Theorem 1.** A function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous if and only if it has closed graph and possesses the property $(*)$.

This theorem implies its own self-generalization:

> **Theorem 2.** A function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ defined on first-countable path-connected topological space $X$ is continuous if and only if it has closed graph and possesses the property $(*)$.

But maybe these two theorems are known? If yes, could you provide me with a suitable reference?

Comment: No idea if there is a standard name, but "weak Świątkowski" (with quotes) gets no hits on Google, so might serve as a backstop.

Comment: Weak Swiatkowski is a possibility, but (*) is much simpler property, not appealing to the continuity at all. It is a kind of weak Darboux property, too. Maybe I will add another remark. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @J.J.Green: it certainly has merits, because it quickly connects the reader to "Świątkowski". But there is a disadvantage as well, since e.g. changing (S) above to a version with just the open interval $I(f(a),f(b))$ changed to the closed one $I[f(a),f(b)]$ would also merit being called "weak Świątkowski", I would think.

Comment: A [**Darboux function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function)?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Darboux seems much stronger, it is a bit like the surjective version of what Taras Banakh is proposing. (oh I see this has been incorporated already)

Comment: If you haven't yet looked through the survey paper [*Darboux like functions*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1337713140) by Richard G. Gibson and Tomasz Natkaniec [Real Analysis Exchange 22 #2 (1996-1997), pp. 492-533], then I recommend starting there, including its bibliography. After this, if you still haven't found anything, perhaps google the title of this paper for more recent papers.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thank you for the link to the paper of Gibson and Natkaniec. Indeed, it contains many Darboux-like properties, but not that I need.

Comment: For anyone curious here's one way to get the theorem ("if" direction). I'll show the Darboux property. Consider wlog $a<b$ with $f(a)<c<f(b).$ Pick a minimal element $(b',f(b'))$ of $\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in I[a,b], f(x)\geq c\}$ in the product order in $\mathbb R^2,$ using the fact that the graph is closed. Then pick a maximal element $(a',f(a'))$ of $\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in I[a,b'], f(x)\leq c\}$ in the product order. If $f(a')<f(b')$ then (*) gives us an $x\in I(a',b')$ with $f(a')\leq f(x)\leq f(b')$ which would contradict the choice of either $a'$ or $b'.$ So we must have $f(a')=c$ or $f(b')=c.$

Comment: @Dap So, this is another application of (*). Very good. Is it known that functions with Darboux property and closed graph are continuous?

Comment: Yes, it suffices that $f$ is Darboux and $f^{-1}(\{r\})$ is closed for each rational $r$: W. Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Chapter 4, exercise 19

Comment: Maybe call it the 'discrete Swiatkowski property'; after all, it is the Swiatkowski property in the discrete topology... I generally feel that it is better to avoid generic adjectives (weak, strong, good, `quasi-' and so on) in terminology, because they are very much overloaded as is.